# How do I adjust the transparency (alpha) of a button in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton, alpha

My button is `flButton` but when I try to set the `alpha` to `0`, it gives me the error

> `Value of type '(Any) -> ()` has no member `alpha`".

Do I have to replace `Any` in the `@IBAction` line?

```
import UIKit

class FirstLaunchView: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var logo1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var smiley1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var subHapp1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var happ1: UILabel!
    @IBAction func flButton(_ sender: Any) {

        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "name")
        //launchDetector = false

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMain", sender: self)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var firstLaunch: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        logo1.alpha = 0
        smiley1.alpha = 0
        subHapp1.alpha = 0
        happ1.alpha = 0
        flButton.alpha = 0         
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `flButton` is an `@IBAction function`. You should either create an `@IBOutlet` for your button or do this in your `function` if you want to keep it:

```
if let button = sender as? UIButton {
    button.alpha = 0
}
```

Or you could just change the type of you `@IBAction function` from:

```
@IBAction func flButton(_ sender: Any)
```

To:

```
@IBAction func flButton(_ sender: UIButton)
```

And then just set `sender.alpha = 0`.

Comment: Actually, changing `Any` to `UIButton` is also a viable solution.

Comment: @Sulthan, that´s true and you don´t even have to redraw the `@IBAction` did not knew that you didn´t have to do it. Have added it as an alternative, thanks.

Comment: The parameter of the action is actually optional, you could also use `flButton()` and access the button using `IBOutlet`. That comes from the dynamicity of Objective-C. The selector does not contain types. It's probably not a good practice to reuse one `IBAction` for multiple buttons if the buttons are not the same kind.

Answer (score 2):

Most simple way is what Rashwan L suggested , create an outlet just like logo1,smiley1 like this.

```
@IBOutlet weak var flButton: UIButton!
```

after that you can easily change your color by

```
flButton.alpha = 0
```